# Java Spring java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring

У меня есть модель:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RSS_FEED")
public class RssFeed {

  @Id
  @Column
  private String title;

  @Column
  @URL
  private String link;

  @Column
  @SafeHtml
  private String description;

  @Column
  @SafeHtml
  private String content;

  @Column
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date pubDate;

  @Column
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date updateDate;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
  private RssStream rssStream;
}
```

Для данной модели есть DAO:

```
@Repository
public class RssFeedDAOImpl implements RssFeedDAO {

  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public RssFeed add(RssFeed rssFeed) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(rssFeed);
    return rssFeed;
  }
}
```

Есть сервис для работы с моделью:

```
@Service
public class RssFeedServiceImpl implements RssFeedService {

  @Autowired
  private RssFeedDAO rssFeedDAO;

  @Override
  public RssFeed add(RssFeed rssFeed) {
    return rssFeedDAO.add(rssFeed);
  }
}
```

И есть трансформер из `spring-integration`:

```
@Component
public class RssTransformer {

  @Autowired
  RssStreamService rssStreamService;

  @Autowired
  RssFeedService rssFeedService;

  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RssTransformer.class);

  @Transformer
  public Message<RssFeed> transform(SyndEntry syndEntry, @Header("BASE_URL") URL url) {
    RssStream stream = rssStreamService.get(url.toString());
    RssFeed rssFeed = new RssFeed();
    rssFeed.setTitle(syndEntry.getTitle());
    rssFeed.setPubDate(syndEntry.getPublishedDate());
    rssFeed.setLink(syndEntry.getLink());
    rssFeed.setRssStream(stream);
    rssFeed.setUpdatedDate(syndEntry.getUpdatedDate());
    SyndContent description = syndEntry.getDescription();
    if(description != null)
      rssFeed.setDescription(description.getValue());
    List contents = syndEntry.getContents();
    if(contents != null && contents.size() > 0)
      rssFeed.setContent(((SyndContent) contents.get(0)).getValue());
    // Следующая строка ошибка
    rssFeed = rssFeedService.add(rssFeed);
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(rssFeed).build();
  }
}
```

Реализация rssStreamService - не привожу т.к. не имеет значения. Все хорошо отрабатывает до момент: `rssFeed = rssFeedService.add(rssFeed);` - вот тут выскакивает ошибка:

```
SEVERE: org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: ;
 nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ; 
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot process message.
```

Что я делаю не так и почему происходит ошибка?